# how can i compare the positions of clones?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have 16 clones in the list.list get shuffle and clones get placed on random places.i have function of swap on click clones swapping their position with its neighbour.now i want to after every click winorLose() function run and compare positions of the list of clonesif they are equal new level will load..till now i have done this.

**Board.cs**

```
void Start () {

       for(int a=GridHeight;a>0;a--){
         for(int b=0;b<GridWidth;b++)
       {
           g =  Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 ( b,a, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

          g.name= g.GetInstanceID().ToString();
          g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

          //LastGem=g.GetComponent<Gem>();


          gemComponent = g.GetComponent<Gem>();
          gems.Add(gemComponent);
          gems1.Add(gemComponent);
          if(a==1 && b==3)
          { 
              gemComponent.cube.renderer.enabled = false;
          }

       }

    }
       //gems.Sort ();
       //gems1.Sort ();

       gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (-2.5f, -2.5f, 0);
    ChangePosition();
       WinOrLose ();
    }

public void ChangePosition() {

       for(int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++) {
         Vector3 temp = gems[i].transform.position;
           randomIndex = Random.Range(0, gems.Count);
         gems[i].transform.position = gems[randomIndex].transform.position;
         gems[randomIndex].transform.position = temp;


       }
       }


    public void SwapGem(Gem gem1)
    {

          gem1start = gem1.transform.position;
          gem1end = gemComponent.transform.position;
          if (gemComponent.IsNeighbourWith (gem1)) {
                 gem2start = gem1end;
                 gem2end = gem1start;
                 gem1.transform.position = gem2start;
                 gemComponent.transform.position = gem2end;

          }

       }

    public void WinOrLose( )
    {  gems1.Sort ();
       for(int i=0;i<gems.Count;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<gems.Count;j++){
          if (gems[i].GetInstanceID()==gems1[j].GetInstanceID()) {
                 print ("match);
          }
         }}
    }
```

**Gems.cs**

```
public void OnMouseDown()
    {

          if (!GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().isSwapping)
       {
                 GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().SwapGem (this);

          }

       GameObject.Find ("board").GetComponent<board> ().WinOrLose ();

    }
```

but it print match always on button click.why i am getting this and lists are not getting compare..??what am i doing wrong?? please help

Comment: Making a 15-puzzle game?

Comment: @   Sergey Krusch yes

Comment: Started from the scratch? :D It is you, isn't it?  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3359315/himani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, man. Your problem is not in "comparing clones". And not in any questions that you have already asked here. Your main problem is that you seem to not understand how your code does work and how it should work. Learn how to debug programs.

1. Familiarize yourself with [Debug.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) and [console](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Console.html).
2. Learn how to use the debugger. Is is a very powerful tool. Go through this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-D6qXaGSC2k

Be patient. Maybe it will take you a day or two to get use to these. But it will give you more than asking even a 1000 questions here on stack overflow.

Comment: If he actually wrote the code himself then he would know of functions such as Debug.log...

Comment: How did you get to such a conclusion?